# Styled Components: Style Parent if child has attribute

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a Parent that has a deeply nested child which can get an attribute if selected.

How do I style the background-color of the parent, only if a deeply nested child has an attribute of 'selected'?

```
<Parent>
 <Child>
  <NestedChild selected>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
const Parent = styled.div`
  &[selected] { // But this only styled the child, not the parent}
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The CSS way

There isn't one - CSS doesn't allow an element to affect styling of its parents, only that of its children or siblings.

### The React purist way

Use the [`useContext` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) along with `createContext` and a context `Provider`, or simply pass a callback down through all the nested levels.

### The hacky-yet-simple React + vanilla JavaScript way

```js
// set up some styles for `has-child-selected` class
// ...

const Parent = ({ ... }) => {
  return <div className="parent">
    ...
  </div>
}

const Child = ({ selected }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.closest('.parent')
      .classList[selected ? 'add' : 'remove']('has-child-selected')
  }, [selected])

  return <div ref={ref}>
    ...
  </div>
}
```

---

**Edit**: I realized I didn't even mention Styled Components in this answer, but I don't think it would change very much. Perhaps someone with more knowledge of Styled Components would be able to enlighten.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with CSS only. So I remember at least. try this.
you can change any tag, and any attr

```css
li:has(> a[href="https://css-tricks.com"]){
  color:red;
}
```

Looks Like it doesn't work at this time.  but check when you see this.
:D :D

Comment: Unfortunately looks like it's [not implemented in any browser yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: too bad. it would be cool to get parent element with child straight from css